# Rust recursion in an async fn

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, rust

I want to use recursion in an async fn, just like:

```
async fn test(data: i32) -> i32 {
    if data == 0 {
        0
    } else {
        test(data - 1).await
    }
}
```

but it says recursion in an `async fn` requires boxing.

So I change it like this:

```
async fn test(data: i32) -> BoxFuture<'static, i32> {
    async move {
        if data == 0 {
            0
        } else {
            test(data - 1).await.await
        }
    }
    .boxed()
}
```

But it again compile error with message: cycle used when computing type of `test::{opaque#0}`
what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` is more or less syntax sugar for returning a `Future`, since you already return one, just remove the `async` from your definiton, it's not needed any more:

```rust
use futures::{FutureExt, future::BoxFuture};
fn test(data: i32) -> BoxFuture<'static, i32> {
    if data == 0 {
        async { 0 }.boxed()
    } else {
        test(data - 1)
    }
}
```

As a rule of thumb, a function should be either `async` or return a `T: Future` not both.

Comment: Alternatively you can box branches individually which removes some indentation and the `await` point e.g `async {0}.boxed()` (or `std::future::ready(0).boxed()`) and `test(data - 1).boxed()`.

Comment: @Masklinn Applied your suggestion, thanks. (And note that the latter case no longer needs a `.boxed()` call, as the function already returns a boxed future.)

Comment: @AurelBílý oh yeah true, even better